# cannot access localhost/phpmyadmin on windows 7 VM

Tags: xampp, phpmyadmin

When i try to connect to localhost/phpmyadmin I get an error in browser "this site cannot be reached"

I am running XAMPP on a virtual box windows 7

what I have done so far:

in config.inc.php file changed:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

My goal is to create a database on mysql, but I cannot access myphpadmin.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Open `C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`. There will be probably some error. I think cookies are wrongly set in php.ini file.